# understanding "append" of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to understand this code written in javascript

```
$(p)[on](click,function (){$[post](login.php,
                    { name:$(this)[attr](id),pass:_0x15x2},
                    function (_0x15x3){$(head)[append](_0x15x3);} 
                   );}
```

It's clear that it associate an event "click" to "p". when the user click, it sends ,using post method, name and pass. But I can't understand the objectif of

```
function (_0x15x3){$(head)[append](_0x15x3);
```

I didn't found any other occurrence of "_0x15x3" at any place in the page that I'm analyzing

Comment: That's really cool....what's your question?

Comment: it's a variable, and is probably being generated on-the-fly. but since you don't show any other code, we have no way of telling what's happening.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: `_0x15x3` is a parameter of the function, it’ll be the value returned by the `POST` call to `login.php`. @user2864740 if `append` is equal to `"append"` then yes, there’s an `append` call.

Comment: So just an FYI, you are probably getting downvoted for not stating exactly what your question is, plus the very very weird way of doing events `$('h1').on('click', function)`.  I'm going to assume you just want to understand what `_0x15x3` actually is?

Comment: This is probably obfuscated code.

Comment: naomik 2 , yes I know beacause it's encoded

Comment: VitaliyG, yes it's ..

I said that the variable _0x15x3 was called in the jquery's function, and it was never declared before. I understand what it does now, the names are stupid because they are encoded with software like http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/ .... It's not my code ..... thanks for you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_0x15x3` is  not a declared variable, it's the parameter name:

```
function (_0x15x3){$(head)[append](_0x15x3);}
```

You could change it to:

```
function (response){ 
    $(head).append(response); 
}
```

Comment: You can name the function parameter whatever you want. `_0x15x3` is a stupid parameter name, but it's just as valid as using `response`.